# Поменять местами столбцы матрицы haskell

Tags: математика, haskell

Никак не могу подходящего ничего придумать. В Data.Matrix есть только switchRows. Как-то это можно сделать? Возможно, над простыми списками. Думал мапить лямбду, да вот составить не смог.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 switchColumns c1 c2  = transpose . (switchRows c2 c1) . transpose
```

Comment: Гениально.